# If outcome is a count from a finite number of possible instances, is binomial or poisson regression more appropriate?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, binomial-distribution, poisson-regression

I have an outcome variable that is the number of criteria participants meet for a diagnosis of substance dependence.

The minimum number of criteria participants can meet is 0 and the maximum is 11. So each participant gets a score which is a count of the number of symptoms out of a possible 11.

I am getting confused about which type of model is more appropriate to model these data. I was taught that count variables usually demand a poisson or negative binomial regression, but recently I found out this is only when there is no theoretical upper limit. Also recently I learned how to do aggregated binomial regression, of the sort shown in the first example [here](https://kkorthauer.org/fungeno2019/methylation/vignettes/1-binomial-regression.html), which seems to fit what I want, a count (i.e. only integers are possible) where there is a definite floor and ceiling on the minimum and maximum score.

**Does aggregated binomial regression sound like the correct modelling approach for my data?**

p.s. is it possible that a simple linear regression would also be suitable? I can see arguments for that too

Comment: Neither would be correct in general, because either (a) assuming the symptoms are independent, the count is a sum of Bernoulli variables with potentially *different* parameters, whence it is not Binomial; or (b) the symptoms are not independent, and again the sum is not Binomial.  The sum definitely is not Poisson in any case.

Comment: thank you @whuber. I think each different symptom would represent a different manifestation of the same underlying latent trait (i.e. addiction). So do you think a gaussian would be more appropriate then?

Comment: In theory, definitely not a Gaussian; as a practical approach, a highly qualified "maybe."  One of the qualifications is that the extreme scores should be rarely observed.

Comment: The distribution of scores is positively skewed, lots of 0s hardly any 11s.

Comment: And what *would* the theoretically most sound model be?

Comment: I indicated two because you haven't supplied enough information about your data and your problem to choose among them.  Other models are possible as well, depending on how much data you have and how well various approximations might work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110675/discussion-between-llewmills-and-whuber).

Comment: Have moved this to chat. What two models did you indicate? Gaussian and...?

Comment: See (a) and (b) in my first comment.